# Play live audio stream - html5

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a desktop application which streams raw PCM data to my browser over a websocket connection. The stream looks like this `...\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff\\...`.

The question is simple: can I play such a stream in HTML with the Web Audio API / WebRTC / ...?

Any suggestions are very welcome!

**code edit**

This code plays noise, randomly generated:

```
function myPCMSource() { 
    return Math.random() * 2 - 3;
}

var audioContext;

try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
} catch(e) {
    alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
}

var bufferSize = 4096;
var myPCMProcessingNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
myPCMProcessingNode.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
    var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
     output[i] = myPCMSource(); 
 }
}
```

So changing the `myPCMSource()` to the websocket stream input, should make it work somehow. But it doesn't. I don't get any errors, but the API is not playing any sound nor noise.

Comment: Not sure if there is a out of box solution for this. But it should be possible using the WebAudioAPI and it's ScriptNode. Maybe I should sit down and write one. Are you using any specific framework to emit the websocket stream?

Comment: My application is written in Python, where I'm using the websocket-client library. I also found this article, where someone is trying to achieve the same thing (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=250989), but still didn't manage to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ScriptProcessorNode, but be aware that if there is too much load on the main thread (the thread that runs your javascript, draws the screen, etc.), it will glitch.

Also, your PCM stream is probably in int16, and the Web Audio API works in terms of float32. Convert it like so:

```
output_float[i] = (input_int16[i] / 32767);
```

that is, go from a [0; 65535] range to a [-1.0; 1.0] range.

**EDIT** 
I was using `output_float[i] = (input_int16[i] / 32767 - 1);`, this [article](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=250989) shows that you should use `output_float[i] = (input_int16[i] / 32767);`. Now it's working fine!

Comment: Oké, so I'm tryig to convert my stream to a byte array, but it's not correct yet. My converted values are between 1:0 and -1:0 , but there still are NaN's. I'm converting with `(parseInt(str.substring(0, 8)), 16) / 32767) - 1;`. Any ideas?

Comment: Get an ArrayBuffer from your WebSocket, and then get an Uint16Array out of it: `var input_int16 = new Uint16Array(event.data);` where event is the event you get from your websocket. Then use my conversion code above.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the `ScriptProcessorNode` is **deprecated**. See [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode) for details. The feature was replaced by [AudioWorklets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorklet) and [the AudioWorkletNode interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode).

In short, a `ScriptProcessorNode` runs outside of the browser's internal audio thread, which creates at least on frame (128 samples) of latency. Worse, the `ScriptProcessorNode` often fails to respond quickly enough, if the thread is busy, so will just randomly drop the ball every so often.

Worklets are basically task-specific workers that run in one of the browsers internal threads (paint, layout, audio etc). Audio worklets run in the audio thread, and implement the guts of custom audio nodes, which are then exposed through the WebAudio API as normal.

Note: You are also able to run WebAssembly inside worklets to handle the processing.

The solution provided above is still useful, as the basic idea holds, but it would ideally use an audio worklet.